# How can I rename all files in sub-directories with prefix of sub-directory name and then move files to new directory?

Tags: php, recursion, copy, rename, move

I basically have a setup like this:

```
C:\Upload\A
C:\Upload\B
C:\Upload\C
C:\Upload\D
C:\Upload\E
```

Where A, B, C, D, E are always different (product IDs) and will always be a different amount (it won't always be 5 sub-directories). Each of these sub-directories contains 24 images numbered numerically 01-24.

I need to create a PHP file that runs remotely through the web (IIS) that looks at the Upload directory, gets the name of each sub-directory and appends that name to beginning of each image file contained within that sub-directory.

So, `C:\Upload\A\01.jpg` would become `C:\Upload\A\A-O1.jpg` as well as the other 23 images in each sub-directory.

The PHP file needs to do the same for every sub-directory within the Upload directory.

Then, once the rename is complete, the PHP needs to copy all of the directories (and their images) from the Upload directory to a different directory.  Once copied, the Upload directory needs to be cleared out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
    define('START_DIR', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/start');
    define('DEST_DIR', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/dest');
    define('SEPARATOR', '\\');

    function firstStage() {
        $d = dir(START_DIR);
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
            if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..')
                secondStage($entry);
        }
        $d->close();
    }

    function secondStage($prefix) {
        $d = dir(START_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix);
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
            if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..')
                rename(START_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . SEPARATOR . $entry, DEST_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . '-' . $entry);
        }
        $d->close();
    }

    firstStage();
?>
```

Simply call `firstStage()` to start the process. Make sure you have read/write access to `START_DIR` and `DEST_DIR`

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try running it "CompileError (2014): Syntax error: unexpected token '}'"...It's referring to the one on line 8.

Comment: Sorry, a semicolon was missing at the end of the line. I updated the answer.

Comment: That worked, but I had to make a slight change to make it fit my directory format requirements. I changed: `rename(START_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . SEPARATOR . $entry, DEST_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . '-' . $entry);`,  
to `rename(START_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . SEPARATOR . $entry, DEST_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix . SEPARATOR . $prefix . '-' . $entry);` and now it fails...it says "Cannot rename...   ... target file exists"

Comment: Ok, I fixed the above comment by adding in `if (!is_dir(DEST_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix)) {
                mkdir(DEST_DIR . SEPARATOR . $prefix);
}` just after the `if($entry...` line.  But now, something else is wrong because I'm getting 2 errors per directory:
_Warning: rename(): Can not rename 'START_DIR\18156' to 'DEST_DIR\18156\18156-': target file exists in runBatch.php on line 22, column 17._

Comment: and the second error: _Warning: rename(): Can not rename 'START_DIR' to 'DEST_DIR\18156\18156-': target file exists in runBatch.php on line 22, column 17._

Comment: 18156 is the prefix (one of the capitol letters from the initial post)

Comment: Could you paste your current code and the directory structure you are operating on into https://www.stypi.com and share the link?

Comment: Keep in mind...the code works perfectly on the server.  It does exactly what it needs to do, but now I'm just trying to get rid of the useless errors.